# Elementary OS App Store - No Network

Tags: appcenter

I am unable to use the app store. After a recent update, it says that I must be connected to the internet, when I am. The only thing I can think of that might be causing this issue is that I have 3 NIC's in my machine due to using VM's. Can anyone please assist?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem.

The solution is in this post:
['no' internet connection within appcenter](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/12099/no-internet-connection-within-appcenter)

Edit your /etc/network/interfaces and add the following:

```
auto eno1
iface eno1 inet dhcp
```

(eno1 might be eth0 or something else, its your Ethernet adapter name)

Then restart your network-manager:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

And it should work

Comment: I still use my other Ethernet ports as bridge connections for vm's this won't affect them will they?